# youtube-dl/youtube-dlg on ubuntu creating same name after downloads

Tags: download, youtube-dl, ubuntu-18.10

good day everyone, (please consider that i researched the error before asking)
so a week ago i installed youtube-dl/youtube-dlg on my ubuntu 18 machine. 
Out of the blue (on tuesday july the 30th 2019) the program started to act weird. Weird in a sense which it never acted before.
After downloading a list of videos (multiple video downloads) the program renames the newly downloaded videos as [underscore issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs8Sk.png).
And it stopped the download of others since it's been "already downloaded".
I ran the terminal the terminal command:

```
~youtube-dl video-url
```

the output was:

```
[youtube:user] playlist: Downloading channel page
WARNING: Unable to downloadwebpage: HTTP Error 404: Not found
[youtube:user] playlist: Downloading page #1
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (caused by <HTTPError 404: 'Not Found'>); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see https://yt-dl.org/update on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and inclue its complete output.
```

Now the verbose output was:

```
➜  ~ youtube-dl --verbose 
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: [u'--verbose']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs UTF-8, out UTF-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] youtube-dl version 2019.07.30
[debug] Python version 2.7.15+ (CPython) - Linux-4.15.0-55-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 3.4.6, ffprobe 3.4.6, phantomjs 2.1.1, rtmpdump 2.4
[debug] Proxy map: {}
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl: error: You must provide at least one URL.
Type youtube-dl --help to see a list of all options.
```

My next step i took was installing the latest version after i removed it from my machine. This fixed one part of the problem. The error in youtube-dlg was not solved by updating, I am still getting the error with the underscore renaming issue.
However I am able to download via the terminal but not all videos. Some of these videos showed this error:

```
[download]   3.4% of ~7.84KiB at 194[download]   3.4% of ~7.84KiB at 194[download]   0.1% of ~1.11MiB at 194[download]   0.3% of ~1.11MiB at  2.[download]   0.6% of ~1.11MiB at  3.[download]   1.3% of ~1.11MiB at  5.[download]   2.8% of ~1.11MiB at  1.[download]   5.6% of ~1.11MiB at  1.[download]   6.9% of ~1.11MiB at  1.[download]   6.9% of ~1.11MiB at  1.[download]   4.3% of ~1.79MiB at 265[download]   4.4% of ~1.79MiB at 656[download]   4.6% of ~1.79MiB at  1.[download]   5.1% of ~1.79MiB at 866[download]   6.0% of ~1.79MiB at  1.[download]   7.7% of ~1.79MiB at  1.[download]  10.3% of ~1.79MiB at  2.[download]  10.3% of ~1.79MiB at  2.47MiB/s ETA 00:13[download] Got server HTTP error: HTTP Error 404: Not Found. Retrying fragment 4 (attempt 1 of 10)...
[download] Got server HTTP error: HTTP Error 404: Not Found. Retrying fragment 4 (attempt 2 of 10)...
[download] Got server HTTP error: HTTP Error 404: Not Found. Retrying fragment 4 (attempt 3 of 10)...
[download] Got server HTTP error: HTTP Error 404: Not Found. Retrying fragment 4 (attempt 4 of 10)...
[download] Got server HTTP error: HTTP Error 404: Not Found. Retrying fragment 4 (attempt 5 of 10)...
```

This is my actual status and I dont know what to look for or where. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem. Solved it this way: deleted the file ~/.config/youtube-dlg/youtube-dl. When running youtube-dlg, it loaded a new youtube-dl. That's all :)